# How to communicate all expressions in javascript scope

Tags: javascript

this question is quite basic,
Here is a sample code what I want to do in javascrtipt:

```
(function getdata(){
  gettrue( true=true );
  gettrue( 1==2 );
  gettrue( 1==1 );
  // write something here to get all three expressions result ? 
  // console.log( [ all three result ] )
})()
```

gettrue(){}

## update:

This question can be used for a test framework:

```
test("several test result:" , function(){
   assert("test1" , true );
   assert("test2" , false )
 })

function test(title , fn){
   console.log("running: " + title)
   fn()
   // write something here to get all result of assert
   //  not more than 2 lines
  }

function assert(str, test){
   if(test){
     console.log(str +" :  PASS ")
   }else{
     console.log(str +" :  Fail ")
   }
   return test
}
```

Comment: it is spelling mistake , should be true==true  . 

The rule is not allowed to use return from gettrue(), and not allowed to change three lines include gettrue

Comment: gettrue return undefined  ,  and  I want to get 3   equal expressions directly

Comment: please help us with some more words. who should communicate? and with whom? and what? when gettrue is just a dummy, why not name it dummy? and - at least - what do you mean with scope in this contect?

Comment: I need some code at end of getdata() to communicate with 3 arguments of gettrue() .   it could be used for test all result of previous gettrue.

Comment: you could also try: `test( function(){   assert( true) ;  assert(false)    } );`

Comment: `function assert( test){ //empty; } ;`

Comment: `function test(fn){
   fn()
// write something here to get all result of assert
}`

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the results *somewhere*. As it is, you're throwing all three away.

An array seems simplest:

```
(function getdata() {
  var results = [
    gettrue( true==true ),
    gettrue( 1==2 ),
    gettrue( 1==1 )
  ];

  console.log(results);
})()
```

Comment: Plus1, but I'd go for `results.push()` myself.  I know it's pedantic, but I'd find that easier to read a year later.

Comment: I like this answer, but gettrue is return nothing,   I want to find a way to get 3 equal expressions directly.

Comment: If `gettrue()` returns nothing, what is it you want to log?

Comment: gettrue, will do log , report, but not return test result,  the main issue here is  , I want to find a way to find all expressions in  getdata scope.

Comment: this could be used for another purpose  ,  in a scope you have 2 assert: test(  function(){ assert( true ) ; assert(false)   })
function test(fn){
  //  how to get both assert expresion , without using return
}

Comment: "find all expressions" "get both assert expressions" - do you want to somehow analyze the code itself and report on the expressions in it? I'll ask again, **what do you want to log**? In your ideal world, `console.log( ... something ...)` would print *what*?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question but are you looking for something like this? Also you cannot set true to anything did you mean true == true?

```
var values = [];

(function getdata(){
  values.push(gettrue( true==true ));
  values.push(gettrue( 1==2 ));
  values.push(gettrue( 1==1 ));

  console.log(values);
})();

function gettrue(val){ return val; }
```

Comment: actually  , not allowed return from gettrue()  and not allowed to change 3 lines with gettrue

Answer (score 0):

assignment `true=true` is not valid.
`gettrue()` is not returning something and missing a parameter.

```
function gettrue(b) { return !!b; }
(function getdata() {
    console.log([
        gettrue(true == true),
        gettrue(1 == 2),
        gettrue(1 == 1),
    ]);
})();
```

Comment: the gettrue()  is just a dummy,    In purpose to show that the question has no relation with what gettrue do

Answer (score 0):

as a conclusion ,  discussed with several experienced programmer .
it is not possible to get all evaluation result without touch  getture or assert  function.

```
var count;
(function getdata(){
  count=0 

  gettrue( true );
  gettrue( 1==2 );
  gettrue( 1==1 );

  gettrue( count==3 )
})()

function gettrue(test ){
  console.log( test ) 
  count++
}
```

for  test framework,  it could be :

```
    var count;

    test("several test result:" , function(){
       assert("test1" , true );
       assert("test2" , false )
     })

    function test(title , fn){
       console.log("running: " + title)
       count = 0 ;
       fn()
       var expectTotal = fn.toString().match(/assert/)

       if(expectTotal)
        assert( title , expectTotal.length == count )
      }

    function assert(str, test){
       if(test){
         console.log(str +" :  PASS ")
       }else{
         console.log(str +" :  FAIL ")
       }
       count ++
       return test
    }
```